# Autoreload of python file in specific path

Tags: python, module, jupyter-notebook, ipython, reload

### Working situation

I have a `hello.py` file with the basic function

```
def say_hello()
    print("hello world")
    return
```

And a `notebook.ipynb` **in the same directory** (making the "import" work)

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2
import hello
```

Then everytime I update the hello.py file, the autoreload works :

```
hello.say_hello() 

Out >>>  "Hello world with autoreload working"
```

### Problematic situation

When the `hello.py` file is not in the same directory I can not use "import" so I have:

```
%load_ext autoreload
%autoreload 2

from importlib.machinery import SourceFileLoader
hello = SourceFileLoader("hello", '/path/to/hello.py').load_module()
```

At first it works :

```
hello.say_hello()

Out >>> "Hello world"
```

But after I edit the python file :

```
def say_hello()
    print("hello world again")
    return
```

And re-execute the function, it returns the previous version of the file AND throws an error

```
hello.say_hello()

Out >>> "Hello world"

[autoreload of  failed: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site- 
packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 244, in check
superreload(m, reload, self.old_objects)
 File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\site-packages\IPython\extensions\autoreload.py", line 376, in superreload
    module = reload(module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\imp.py", line 314, in reload
    return importlib.reload(module)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\Lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 166, in reload
    _bootstrap._exec(spec, module)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 589, in _exec
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'name'
]
```

How to autoreload a Python file in a specific path, from a Jupyter notebook ?

Answer (score 0):

This is an `ImportError` python version - 3.7.

Have `importlib.reload()` raise ImportError if the module's spec is not found.

- [raise ImportError if the module's spec is not found](https://bugs.python.org/issue29851)

Comment: I updated my question. Unfortunately I don't think this is an issue with the path as it is correctly imported the first time (say_hello() is working) but not when the python file is modified